# Metering gas used for heating water in a multi-dwell building with one boiler

Tags: plumbing, heating, boiler

I rent in a multi-dwell building. We are not directly charged for hot water but trying to figure out if we are indirectly charged via the Con-Ed gas bill.

Is it possible to meter gas usage for the heating of water in a building with one gas-powered boiler? If so, how? I have access to the boiler room. What should I look for to confirm?

Answer (score 3):

Nope. One boiler means only one opportunity to meter the gas.

Answer (score 3):

They could meter the hot water you use from the boiler individually, but not the gas used to fire the boiler.